# Do you need to verify torrented ISO?

Tags: system-installation, iso, bittorrent

I torrented the ISO and was wondering whether or not I needed to verify the ISO, for security purposes.

How secure are torrent downloads, in relation to file integrity?

I'm using rTorrent if that matters.

Comment: The torrent program itself should validate the integrity of the file (otherwise it should report that the torrent is incomplete or has other problems). But it never hurts to double check and running an `md5sum` doesn't take much time.

Comment: So if you download via Torrent you don't have to check with GPG?

Comment: Check what with GPG? IIRC the ISOs themselves aren't directly signed, but the MD5SUMS (and SHA1SUMS and SHA256SUMS) files are. So if you do decide to verify with `md5sum`, you should verify the MD5SUMS file.

Comment: @muru Is checking an ISO with a GPG verified MD5SUMS file different from checking with GPG, when checking for verification that it hasn't been changed since Canonical published it?

Comment: Well: What will you do with GPG on the ISO?

Comment: I'm talking hypothetically, as there isn't a GPG file for the ISOs, but if there was.

Comment: Hypothetically I'd think the verifying the ISO itself would be more expensive (take longer), but otherwise, no. The end result should be the same: ISO verified.

Comment: Makes sense. So your saying it is safe to use a ISO that had been torrented but not checked in any other way.

Comment: No, since there's no guarantee of the torrent file itself being valid. You should verify the ISO with `md5sum` or one of the other hashes just to be sure. As long as the torrent file is good, however, torrenting should detect invalid downloaded data.

Comment: But if we can't assume the torrent file is correct then we have to verify the hash with GPG.

Comment: Yes, of course. The only safe way is to do so.

Comment: I agree. I think we've come to a conclusion and a good answer. Would you like to post an answer, or do you want me to write it up?

Comment: I think you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you do need to check the ISO** using a checksum that is verified by the **GPG** file.

The torrented ISO is most likely the file the torrent was intended for you to download. However, the torrent file isn't necessarily the one provided by Canonical. Because of this you must check the integrity of the file using a checksum that you verify using GPG.

### Instructions for Verifying ISO

1. Obtain ISO you wish to download.
2. Download the checksum using `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/SHA256SUMS` replacing 14.10 with the release you downloaded.
3. Download the checksum GPG file using `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/SHA256SUMS.gpg` again replacing 14.10 with the release number.
4. Add the Ubuntu CD Image Signing Key to your keyring with `gpg --recv-keys 0xFBB75451`
5. Verify the checksum using `gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS`. If it gives you something like `gpg: Signature made 2014-07-25T01:53:21 CEST using DSA key ID FBB75451
   gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
   gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
   gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
   Primary key fingerprint: C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451` than the key is good.

Comment: If the torrent is from an official site, you can just right click on the torrent in the torrent program and choose verify files (and if after this operation it is not 100 % start the torrent until it is). Official means Download section indicated by your distribution main page.

Comment: @iuga You still need to verify for security, by using GPG verified checksum.

Comment: @iugamarian That would not serve any purpose. Torrents are integrity-checked piece-by-piece during download. The only situations in which a torrent client's "verify" feature is useful is to check for hardware problems, or file mismatches when attaching torrents to preexisting files. As for security, it's only as secure as the place you downloaded the torrent from. An "official site" could still theoretically be hijacked, but the GPG keys are kept extremely secure.

Comment: This guide misses the step to actually check that the content of the iso matches the hash stored in SHA256SUMS: `sha256sum --check SHA256SUMS` (Reports of missing files are no issue as long as the file you are interested in is listed as "OK".) Maybe it is better to refer to the [up to date documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto) for stuff like this.